# Getting Key_error while dividing two numerical columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm having the petrole_price dataset and I'm checking the condition whether it's greater than yesterday or not. If it is true it will create a subset.

```
petrole_price

   Country Today Yesterday
0   India   120    117 
1   US       90     92
2   UAE      32     31
3   Russia   70     69
4   UK       55     55
```

While execute below code I'm getting error as **key_error 'Today'**

```
petrole_price = petrole_price[petrole_price['Today'] > petrole_price['Yesterday']]
```

Here is the entire error:

```
petrole_price = petrole_price[petrole_price['Today'] > petrole_price['Yesterday']]
  File "/home/tgphamifm/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/tgphamifm/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Today'
```

Comment: What is the output from `petrole_price.columns`? It may be possible you have extra whitespace in your columns.

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker, when I print each column they are printing. No issue with column names.

Comment: Would you share the exact output from `print(petrole_price.columns)`? it should look something like -> `Index(['Country', 'Today'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @HenryEcker Yup I got same. Index(['Country', 'Today', 'Yesterday'], dtype='object')

Comment: Okay what happened between having the column then trying to filter your dataframe. Can you show the steps before this filter?

Comment: Stupid idea but since it says `df` at the top of your displayed DataFrame, could it be that `petrole_price` is not your DataFrame and you would have to use `df['Today']` instead?

Comment: Hi @Hein, for understanding I have given as df but I changed.

Comment: Very strange. Your code should work

Comment: @swarna No problem, that's why I framed it as stupid :D

Comment: @HenryEcker There are no steps before this filter.